# How can I check the existence of web pages from a script launched in the Google Cloud Run?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp) to learn how to use headless Chrome in the Google cloud in order to run a script to see if some pages they exist.

As I don't have Docker installed I tried:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my_service
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission
```

The file I want to run is :

```
import selenium

from collections import defaultdict
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_red = pd.read_csv("tickers_september_2017_updated.csv")

tradable = []
for ticker in df_red['Ticker']:
    print(ticker)
    location = "https://www.etoro.com/markets/" + ticker.lower() 
    driver.get(location) # vamaos al ticker
    time.sleep(2)
    current_url = driver.current_url # almacenamos la dirección donde realmente nos lleva
    if current_url == location: # Si sigue siendo el mismo, significa que el teletipo es negociable.
        tradable.append(ticker)
```

I also tried with request but the pages always exist, it does not redirect, it answers a 200 Ok and a valid html, but that html contains an iframe and I suspect that the content of the iframe is dynamically loaded by js. If so, I'm afraid that doing it without selenium would be too complicated.

## Update

I found [a repository](https://github.com/garywu/google-compute-engine-selenium) with scripts that seem to install the necessary things to run selenium. It seemed to be a good way to check if pages existed. So I followed the instructions and had the expected output but when I want to launch my own script I have the following error:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ python3 tradable.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tradable.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/mikempc3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/mikempc3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/mikempc3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/mikempc3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mikempc3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_respons
e
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 4.9.0-12-amd64 x86_64)
```

## Update 2

I am now getting started with Docker

Comment: Even if you use selenium, then too you will have to check whether it's throwing a captcha or re-directing by going through the html of the website

Comment: @bigbounty Yes I did it locally and it doesn't.

Comment: It seems as if the service account being used by the Compute Engine VM does not have enough permissions either to create the Cloud Build build (assign a relevant role such as [Cloud Build Editor](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/iam-roles-permissions)) or the image at Container Registry (check the relevant permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#iam)).

Comment: Hi! Author of the tutorial here, sorry you're having trouble. Looking at https://www.etoro.com/markets/, it seems like this URL would require some sort of login, is that correct? How are you handling that here?

Comment: @DustinIngram really honored having you there! To check if a page exist I don’t need to log in. I either arrive on the page or it seems I am redirected on the login page. Looking closer it does not redirect it gives back a 200 and a valid html but that html contains an iframe that leads me somewhere (I’m not an expert)

Comment: @DustinIngram for instance: etoro.com/markets/mt (Arcelor Mittal, which seems not to be taken in charge, at least it doesn’t appear) and etoro.com/markets/aapl (where you can see the charts, price ...)  (sorry for the re-poke, there were a mistake in the preceding comments)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this looks like a single-page JavaScript application which will be challenging to scrape. It looks like that website offers an API: https://api-portal.etoro.com/, which might be a better approach.

Comment: @DustinIngram Damn. I managed to do it locally by verifying the URL was the same after waiting 2secs. Regarding the API, unfortunately, it seems nobody answers when we call for an API key